How to disable Auto-Enable Deletion Vectors in databricks workspace using api?
There's no documentation on how to disable Auto-Enable Deletion Vectors in databricks workspace. Basically it is a settings with drop down. The other URL used for changing the settings is not working (/api/2.0/workspace-conf).

I tried to update the settings using '/api/2.0/workspace-conf' URL with key as 'autoEnableDeletionVectorVal'. It is not working.
